# JavaScript not work properly inside PHP while

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop

This function only works for the first selection,for example, if I choose id_rayon = 1 (is the first order of the data in the table), I can choose id_gardu based id_penyulang on id_rayon = 1, but if I choose another id_rayon id_gardu selection does not appear

```
        <div class="w3-half">
          <label>Penyulang</label>
          <select class="w3-select w3-border" name="id_penyulang" onchange="pilih_penyulang(this.value);">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <?php 
              $id_rayon=$row['id_rayon'];
              $vendor=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `penyulang` where id_rayon=$id_rayon"); 
              while($row_vendor=$vendor->fetch_array())
              {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_vendor['id_penyulang'];?>"><?php echo $row_vendor['nama_penyulang'];?></option>
            <?php 
              }
            ?>
          </select>
```

/this only displays the first id and doesn't loop even though it is in the php while loop

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function pilih_penyulang(id_penyulang)
          {
            $.ajax(
            {
              url: 'http://localhost/arrester/option_gardu.php',
              data : 'id_penyulang='+id_penyulang,
              type: "post", 
              dataType: "html",
              timeout: 10000,
              success: function(response)
              {
                $('#dom_gardu').html(response);
              }
            });
          }
      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-half">
      <label>Gardu</label>
      <select class="w3-select w3-border" name="id_gardu" id="dom_gardu">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

and this is dom_gardu file that will be called by javascript

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

$id_penyulang = $_POST['id_penyulang'];
$query= $mysqli->query('select * from gardu where id_penyulang="'.$id_penyulang.'"');
while($data=$query->fetch_array()){
    echo '<option value="'.$data['id_gardu'].'">'.$data['nama_gardu'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

[my webpage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvymh.png)
[my table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z48Fs.png)

Comment: Have you tried it with https instead of http? `url: 'https://localhost/arrester/option_gardu.php'`

Comment: Are you sure, you have more than one row with corresponding `id_rayon` in `penyulang` table?

Comment: Need to do some basic debugging. Is ajax request made (look in browser dev tools network). Is request successful? Does it contain expected response? etc..

Comment: @wormi4ok yes im sure i have more row

Comment: @Miles07 if im use https a message error is "jQuery_3_2_1.min.js:4 POST https://localhost/arrester/option_gardu.php net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE"